# subtree merge requests with [git subtree]

Tags: git, gitlab, git-subtree

We have six projects which use some common **subprojects** that was handled by [submodule](/questions/tagged/submodule), and now we have chosen to use [git-subtree](/questions/tagged/git-subtree).

These **subprojects** are not standalone and each on has one branch,  **master**.

For instance, here is what **projectA** & **projectB** projects look like:

```
projectA:
  |_.git/
  |_src/
  |_app/
  |_plugins
        |__subproject1
        |__subproject3
        |__subproject12

projectB:
  |_.git/
  |_src/
  |_app/
  |_plugins
        |__subproject3
        |__subproject8
```

We can see here that **subproject3** is common between **projectA** and **projectB**.

> Usecase1

**projectA** has made evolve **subproject3** from **v1.3.0** to **v1.4.0**.

**subproject3** is still on **v1.3.0** in the project **projectB** and should remain like that for a while.

However, a bug has been discovered in the **v1.3.0** inside **projectB**. So **projectB** should be fixed without retrieving **v1.4.0** of **subproject**. In the same time, **v1.4.0** should get the same fix as **v1.3.0**.

> With [submodule](/questions/tagged/submodule)

We used to :

1. create new branch **hotfix/bla** in **subproject3**
2. fix the bug
3. create a tag **v1.3.1** based on the fix commit
4. merge the hotfix into master
5. create the tag **v1.4.1**
6. switch to **v1.3.1**
7. commit the new **subproject3** version in **projectB**
8. After that, we set the version of **subproject3** to **v1.4.1** in the project **projectA**.

Here is what `git log --decorate --all --graph` in **subproject3** (inside **projectB**) gives.

```
*   f923c0d (tag: v1.4.1, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge branch 'hotfix'
|\
| * cb8213d (HEAD, tag: v1.3.1, origin/hotfix, hotfix) fix #4.1
* | bfb3008 (tag: v1.4.0) [plug1] #8
* | 25ccbbd [plug1] #7
* | ff22c34 #6
* | cb9f3ab #5
|/
* 1e750fe (tag: v1.3.0) #4
```

> With [git-subtree](/questions/tagged/git-subtree)

**projectB** has **subproject3** set to **master^^^^**, while **projectA** has **subproject3** set to **master**. (no need for tags on plugins with [git-subtree](/questions/tagged/git-subtree))

So, we:

1. Fix the bug inside **projectB**
2. create a [git](/questions/tagged/git) commit for **projectB**
3. push to master fails which is normal, so we push to a new branch **hotfix**
4. create a merge request on [gitlab](/questions/tagged/gitlab) ( **hotfix -> master**) and accept it manually :(
5. Now master is safe again

This surely works, but what annoys us is that we can't avoid processing *step 4* manually. AFAIK, there is no way to automate it in [git-subtree](/questions/tagged/git-subtree).

So to summarize, we're very happy with [git-subtree](/questions/tagged/git-subtree) because it allows us to (almost) not take care of the plugins in terms of git commits etc, as we automated `git subtree push` through [git-hooks](/questions/tagged/git-hooks).

However, the manual **step 4** is left and we can't automate it so far. Sometimes, some of our developers forget to create merge requests, so **master** remains vulnerable.

Is there a way to automate **step 4** (through [git-subtree](/questions/tagged/git-subtree) ideally)? What're our options?